# How to format sql's return value in php?

Tags: php, sql

In this case, I can get return value from sql.

```
$estateGroup = 
    Estate_base::select('id')->whereIn('name',$request->estateName)->get();
```

but `$estateGroup` will be like this: `[{id:1},{id:2}]`

I want to change `[{id:1},{id:2}]` to `[1,2]`

so I doing like following:

```
    $estateGroup = 
        Estate_base::select('id')->whereIn('name',$request->estateName)->get();
    $idGroup=[];
    foreach ($estateGroup as $estate) {
        array_push($idGroup, $estate->id);
    }
```

Is there any way that I can format value more easier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP 7 you [can](https://3v4l.org/7BGaK) use [`array_column()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) function with list of objects:

```
$idGroup = array_column($estateGroup, 'id');
```

It's shortest (and probably fastest) way to extract values of same property from multiple objects. The note from documentation:

> 7.0.0: Added the ability for the input parameter to be an array of objects.

Comment: Thank's, it seems the best way in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php). By the way it will do same thing as you are doing but in less code.

```
$idGroup = array_map(function($estate) { return $estate->id;}, $estateGroup);
```